# Why is Apache saying that DocumentRoot does not exist even though it does?

Tags: apache

I am working on configuring Apache virtual hosts for the first time. I configured apache to use virtual hosts using [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/apache-virtual-host/) tutorial. When I restart apache it says the document root for one of my "virtual" links does not exist -- even though the file exists on my system. Why is Apache saying this? How can I fix it?

```
prompt$ sudo apachectl -k restart
Password:
Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Abrams-MacBook-Air-3.local for ServerName
prompt$ cat /usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com 
<p> it works </p>
```

Comment: Is dummy-host.example.com a directory or a file? It should be a directory, your cat statement makes it look like it's an html file.

Comment: @DVG I have it as a file. I did not know it was supposed to be a directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mv /usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com /usr/docs/index.html
mkdir /usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com
mv /usr/docs/index.html /usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com/index.html
```

This will rename your file to a proper index.html file, create the subdirectory you actually want and then file the new file under the host directory like you actually want.